# LibGdx render a sprite on top of a isometric tile

Tags: libgdx, isometric

So I have this isometric map, and I want to draw sprites on top of tiles.
but ofcourse if I get the position of the isometric tile, and I draw a sprite on that position, it wont draw on top of the tile since the isomap is rotated.

here if I draw a color cube for each tile position....

[image]

---

##

**So my question is, what I have to do to draw this sprite on top of the tile?**
Im using `IsometricTiledMapRenderer`

Thanks in advance, I have been searching for this the whole day and my lack of english vocabulary is not helping for searching

---

EDIT: @dfour answer almost did the trick.. heres how it looks now...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to convert Cartesian values to isometric values.
This [Isometric Tutorial](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-isometric-worlds-a-primer-for-game-developers--gamedev-6511) should help.

```
//Cartesian to isometric:

isoX = cartX - cartY;
isoY = (cartX + cartY) / 2;

//Isometric to Cartesian:

cartX = (2 * isoY + isoX) / 2;
cartY = (2 * isoY - isoX) / 2;
```

These functions show how you can convert from one system to another:

```
function isoTo2D(pt:Point):Point{
  var tempPt:Point = new Point(0, 0);
  tempPt.x = (2 * pt.y + pt.x) / 2;
  tempPt.y = (2 * pt.y - pt.x) / 2;
  return(tempPt);
}

function twoDToIso(pt:Point):Point{
  var tempPt:Point = new Point(0,0);
  tempPt.x = pt.x - pt.y;
  tempPt.y = (pt.x + pt.y) / 2;
  return(tempPt);
}
```

Comment: It did get better but still, is off, see my edited question, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Can you supply some or your render code so I can adjust my example to match your program?